# django on production server(ubuntu)

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx

I'm trying to ship my web application to the production server. My setup is **django-gunicorn-nginx** by following this tutorial http://ijcdigital.com/blog/django-gunicorn-and-nginx-setup/. I've not installed supervisor yet for checking purpose. There is no problem in the configuration setup which is perfect and I got the Django welcome page. Then I loaded my apps into the project. And then I run `gunicorn_django --bind=127.0.0.1:8001` It shows

```
cover.backgroundmodel: "background": To use ImageFields, you need to install the Python Imaging Library. Get it at http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ .
cover.backgroundmodel: "tmpbg": To use ImageFields, you need to install the Python Imaging Library. Get it at http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ .
2012-05-22 14:24:02 [15359] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 15359)
2012-05-23 00:54:02 [15360] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15360
2012-05-22 14:24:02 [15360] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 15360)
2012-05-23 00:54:02 [15349] [INFO] Handling signal: int
2012-05-23 00:54:02 [15349] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

But I've successfully installed everything including PIL and other image libraries. The interesting thing is I'm getting my project running perfectly on my computer. But I can't identify the cause of the problem in the production server.

Again I tried installing `pip install PIL` It shows like this https://gist.github.com/2771119 Why is it so? why I can't able to install PIL now which I successfully installed before while installing django.

Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install [python-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/fr/lucid/python-dev) package because you haven't header files of python to compile PIL.

Comment: @Furbeenator Why stackoverflow is showing **You can accept the answer in x mins**? Is that a good time?